# Error with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6 with FPM

Tags: apache2, php-fpm

I have a Vagrant machine with:

- Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
- PHP 5.6 and PHP-FPM.

In some case I get this error: `500 Internal Server Error`.

And I have this in message in `php5-fpm.log`:

```
[09-Dec-2015 20:01:24] WARNING: [pool www] child 608 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 368.307577 seconds from start
```

And in the `error.log` file I have this message:

```
[Wed Dec 09 20:01:24.944748 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 535:tid 140236008924928] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.33.1:57201] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: read failed
[Wed Dec 09 20:01:24.945014 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 535:tid 140236008924928] [client 192.168.33.1:57201] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
```

I have check my `php.ini` to update the options like this:

```
max_execution_time = 360
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 512M
```

This is my opcache file configuration:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=0 ; for now disabled
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=2000  ; Using "find /home -type f -print | grep php | wc -l" produced 226540 php files.
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.use_cwd=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

And this is my `php5-fpm.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I have read about the bug, but I don't find a clear way to solve it, or to know what happened with the app to give back this error.